# Hide/Remove and Show/Restore options in a Select2 dropdown box

Tags: jquery-select2

I have an issue where I need to hide or remove options from a select2 dropdown when selected.  These selections fill a list.  I would rather not remove the option because if the user removes it from the freshly populated list then it should return to the dropdown with its place in the order restored.  I've tried the following:

```
.select2-results .select2-disabled,  .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] { 
    display: none;
}

$('#optionId').prop('disabled', true);
```

With the prop being set in the jQuery change block.  I just can't get this piece.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.  If the disable is wrapped like so:

```
$(#selectId).select2('destroy');
$(#optionId).prop('disabled', true);
$(#selectId).select2();
```

then the disabled setting will be honored by select2 and the the display none will make the item disappear.  To make it reappear, just follow the same steps with the disabled property set to 'false'.